# Why isn’t my input-based if statements working in C?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

For some reason, my code isn’t working in C.

Please check the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
while (1){
printf(“Is Python a programming language? “);
char question[4];
scanf(“%s”, &question);

if (strcmp(question, “yes”) == 0 || (strcmp(question, “YES”) == 0 || (strcmp(question, “Yes”) == 0 ))){ //the reason why I’m using so many “or” statements is because idk how to lowercase the input (pls help me if you can)
printf(“Correct”);
} else {
printf(“Incorrect”);
continue;
}
}
```

Comment: `printf(“` <<- that is not a normal double quote.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.  To help narrow down the problem and focus our attentions in the right area, could you explain exactly what you mean by "isn't working"?  Are you getting any warnings or errors from your compiler?  What is the behavior of the program and how does it differt from the expected behavior?

Comment: Hey, so it just keeps printing “incorrect” even when it’s correct (either entered “yes”, or “YES”, or “Yes)

Comment: Enable compiler warnings so you would know to use `scanf("%s", question);`

Comment: Cheetah I’m not sure what you mean by enable compiler warnings…

Comment: Your indentation is is non-existent, you have extra parentheses, you were using incorrect double quote characters, you don't need the `&` in the line that calls `scanf`, and your buffer is very small, but I don't think there are any problems that would cause the output to be incorrect like you describe.  The code works fine for me when I clean up these issues.
How about you debug this by adding a loop to print out the integer value of all characters in `question`, right after `scanf` returns?  Maybe your terminal is adding some weird extra characters to the input.

Comment: `char question[4]` is too small, and is an invitation to disaster.  When you're allocating arrays to hold strings the user is going to type, always allocate them comfortably larger than the longest string you imagine the user might type.  Don't make them the exact size as what the user is supposed to type, and especially don't imagine that by making them a certain size, you're limiting what the user can type.  Users can (and will) type whatever they want!

Comment: Waht do people mean by “incorrect double quotes”? Can you please explain what type of quotes am I supposed to use then?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `OR` in if does not cover all possible permutations. It can be also `yEs` od `yeS` etc etc.

```
char *strtouppper(char *str)
{
    char *wrk = str;
    while(*wrk) {*wrk = toupper((unsigned char)*wrk); wrk++;}
    return str;
}

int main(void)
{
    char answer[4];

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Is Python a programming language? ");
        if(scanf(" %3s", answer) != 1) {printf("\n\nInput error");break;};

        if(!strcmp("YES", strtouppper(answer)))
            printf("\nCorrect\n");
        else 
            printf("\nIncorrect\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/vahd9be9M

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting this but this code is ded tough for me (I can’t understand what it’s doing since it looks complicated), and woah I loved the Explorer Compiler website, never knew this existed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
char * low(char * str){//a function for solve lowercase and uppercase and mix
 for(int i = 0; str[i]; i++){
    str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
 }
}
int main(){
while (1){
    printf("Is Python a programming language? ");
    printf("\n");
    char question[4];
    scanf("%s", question);
    low(question);
    if (strcmp(question, "yes") == 0 ){ 
    printf("\nCorrect");
    break;} 
    else {
    printf("\nIncorrect");
    continue;}
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting all this code, but I’m kind of confused, I didn’t create that lowercase-uppercase function but other than that, what’s different? I don’t really need those many “\n” either.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).